# Nested list of sections and content - Hugo

Tags: hugo

I have a series of nested sections that contain recipes, grouped by type of dish, e.g.:

```
content
└─ recipes
   ├─ _index.md
   ├─ bread
   │  ├─ _index.md
   │  ├─ beer_rolls.md
   │  ├─ ciabatta.md
   │  └─ potato_bread.md
   ├─ dessert
   │  ├─ _index.md
   │  ├─ chocolate_brownies.md
   │  ├─ elderberry_pie.md
   │  └─ victoria_sponge_cake.md
   └─ mains
      ├─ _index.md
      ├─ bean_chilli.md
      ├─ braised_leeks.md
      └─ yorkshire_pudding.md
```

I want to write a `list.html` for `content/recipes/_index.md`, to produce a nested list that reflects the directory structure in `recipes/`, such that the first level of the list links to the subsection e.g. `bread` or `dessert`, and the second level of the list links to the individual recipes, e.g. `bread/beer_rolls.md` or `mains_bean_chilli.md`.

What does the `list.html` contain? Do I need to have multiple `list.html` files, one for each nested subsection?

Comment: [List page templates](https://gohugo.io/templates/lists#example-list-templates)
That's a good description of how to use list page templates. It's straightforward and clear. It gives example code. If you get bugged. Let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With help from [this example](https://github.com/gbmhunter/blog/blob/master/layouts/partials/menu_recursive.html), I constructed the following system, which works well for me:

in `layouts/recipes/list.html` I included this:

```
{{ if (eq .Title "Recipes") }}
  <ul class="postlist">
    {{ range .Sections.ByTitle }}
      <li>            
        <a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a>
        {{ partial "recursive.html" . }}
      </li>
    {{ end }}
  </ul>
{{ else }}
  <ul class="postlist">
    {{ range .RegularPages }}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}">{{ .Title | markdownify }}</a>
    </li>
    {{ end }}
  </ul>
{{ end }}
```

And in `layouts/partials/recursive.html` I included this:

```
{{ $child_pages := union .Sections .Pages }}
<ul>
  {{ range $child_pages.ByTitle }}
  <li>                                    
    <a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}"> {{ .Title }} </a>
    {{ if or (.Sections) (.Pages) }}
    {{ partial "recursive.html" . }}
    {{ end }}
  </li>
  {{ end }}
</ul>
```

`content/recipes/_index.md` looks like this:

```
---
title: "Recipes"
---
```

and for example `content/recipes/drinks/_index.md` looks like this:

```
---
title: "Drinks"
---
```

This produces a page at `./recipes` which contains a grouped list, where the first level includes links to further list pages (e.g. `./recipes/bread`), which themselves contain links to the recipes in that group. All recipes are also listed below their parent group on `./recipes`.

Comment: You also can do `eq .CurrentSection .FirstSection` instead of `eq .Title "Recipes"`. This can let you avoid hardcoding section's title for a more universal approach.